# how to detect android application using namespace?

Tags: namespaces, detect

I'm Trying to detect whether specified app is available on device or not, by using `namespace`.

I have tried using `intent` but it's not working for UC browser.

```
<a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;=package=com.google.zxing.client.android;S.browser_fallback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fzxing.org;end"> Take a QR code    </a>
```

Thanks in advance